# Easiest Way to Convert Smart, Curly Quotes to Dumb, Straight Quotes in Notepad++?

Tags: notepad++, quotes

What is the easiest/most efficient way to globally replace all smart/curved single and double quotes with dumb/straight single and double quotes in Notepad++?

Ideally this would not involve the Find and Replace commands, in that I would prefer not to have to continually retype the material in the Find and Replace fields.

Comment: Still no good answers to this question??  There is opportunity here for someone to create a plug-in or define a macro to handle double and single smart quotes.

Answer (score 1):

I am having the same issue, also in notepad++. I tried the above solutions and they did not work for me. I also disabled the smart quotes in Microsoft Word before copying and pasting, but it still wouldn't use the straight quotes.

The only thing that worked for me was, in notepad++, highlight one of the smart quotes, hit Ctrl + H and replace it with a straight quote. I know you wanted to avoid the Find & Replace feature, but you only have to do this twice (once for the opening quote and once for the closing quote).

I would love to find a quicker solution, but this is the only thing I have been able to find so far.

Answer (score 1):

MSDOS to the rescue.

Just open a CMD window and at the c:> prompt type

> copy con: myfile.txt [Enter]

Paste in your text and finish with Ctrl-Z

Your text with straight quotes is in myfile.txt

Please note that indents are gone too, you can avoid this with converting TAB to spaces (under Edit in Notepad++) before you paste.

Answer (score 1):

**Notepad++ Macro to Remove Smart Quotes**

You can record a macro to replace `&#x2018;` and `&#x2019;` with a straight single quote, and `&#x201C;` and `&#x201D;` with the standard double quote character.  It can be challenging to type the right characters.  I made this some time ago so it's probably easier for you to copy the macro steps that I've included below.

The macros are saved at %AppData%\Notepad++\shortcuts.xml (Windows logo key + E and copy&paste `%AppData%\Notepad++\`)

You can edit your *shortcuts.xml* file and paste the code below into the `<Macros>` section. You'll need to use an editor other than Notepad++ or it will overwrite your changes.  After you restart Notepad++ the macro should be visible on your macro menu.

```
        <Macro name="Remove Smart Quotes" Ctrl="no" Alt="no" Shift="no" Key="0">
            <Action type="3" message="1700" wParam="0" lParam="0" sParam="" />
            <Action type="3" message="1601" wParam="0" lParam="0" sParam="&#x2018;" />
            <Action type="3" message="1625" wParam="0" lParam="0" sParam="" />
            <Action type="3" message="1602" wParam="0" lParam="0" sParam="&apos;" />
            <Action type="3" message="1702" wParam="0" lParam="768" sParam="" />
            <Action type="3" message="1701" wParam="0" lParam="1609" sParam="" />

            <Action type="3" message="1700" wParam="0" lParam="0" sParam="" />
            <Action type="3" message="1601" wParam="0" lParam="0" sParam="&#x2019;" />
            <Action type="3" message="1625" wParam="0" lParam="0" sParam="" />
            <Action type="3" message="1602" wParam="0" lParam="0" sParam="&apos;" />
            <Action type="3" message="1702" wParam="0" lParam="768" sParam="" />
            <Action type="3" message="1701" wParam="0" lParam="1609" sParam="" />

            <Action type="3" message="1700" wParam="0" lParam="0" sParam="" />
            <Action type="3" message="1601" wParam="0" lParam="0" sParam="&#x201C;" />
            <Action type="3" message="1625" wParam="0" lParam="0" sParam="" />
            <Action type="3" message="1602" wParam="0" lParam="0" sParam='&quot;' />
            <Action type="3" message="1702" wParam="0" lParam="768" sParam="" />
            <Action type="3" message="1701" wParam="0" lParam="1609" sParam="" />
            
            <Action type="3" message="1700" wParam="0" lParam="0" sParam="" />
            <Action type="3" message="1601" wParam="0" lParam="0" sParam="&#x201D;" />
            <Action type="3" message="1625" wParam="0" lParam="0" sParam="" />
            <Action type="3" message="1602" wParam="0" lParam="0" sParam='&quot;' />
            <Action type="3" message="1702" wParam="0" lParam="768" sParam="" />
            <Action type="3" message="1701" wParam="0" lParam="1609" sParam="" />
        </Macro>
```

Answer (score 0):

If it's OK that all the formatting gets wiped out, I've found I can select all the text, then change the Language to "MS-DOS style."

Then, still with all text selected, "Encode in UTF-8." You'll have to save it; N++ defaults to .nfo which works for me.

At this point it's as clean as if opened in plain Notepad.

Took me forever to find this fix.

Comment: Just noting that this didn't work for me using Notepad++ 7.2 on Windows 7 - changing the language to "MS-DOS Style" did seem to remove any formatting but left the curly quotes in place. I resorted to four find and replace commands, one each for the left and right single and double quotation marks.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest clicking on the Macro tab in the navigation and click "start recording" highlight the curved opening quote then Ctrl+ H and use the find and replace tool to change them all to the straight quotes. Do the same for the closing quote and then go back to macro to stop recording. In the drop down on the macro tab click the "Save recorded macro". You can title it fix quotes. Now whenever you pull content from other places you can run the fix quote macro which will automatically correct all quotes in the future! :)